# "Straight down that way, then a *hard* to the left" : noun, or rather adj of elliptical material?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, ellipses

From Shameless US, season 9 episode 5, minute 20:12:

> Straight down that way, then a hard to the left.

[Here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=shameless-us&episode=s09e05) is a transcript of the episode.

Is hard here a noun, or rather adj of elliptical material?

Comment: What's the source of the sentence? Are you sure that there was an indefinite article there (instead of e.g. "uh")?

Comment: @Laurel Shameless US, season 9 episode 5, minute 20:12

Comment: What is the source of this sentence? I have never heard this. I would expect "straight down that way, then (take/make) a hard left". Note: I wrote this before seeing the other comments. Laurel's version makes good sense.

Comment: In my vernacular it’d either be “ then hard to the left” or “ then a hard left”  but this seems to combine the two into an ungrammatical form.

Comment: @Jim could you say what your vernacular is?

Comment: In context, this line is a penis joke, so it probably doesn't make sense to analyze it purely in terms of how we give directions. I'd guess there's something going on with intonation that makes it make more sense, but without a video or audio clip it's impossible to say.

Comment: My vernacular is general AmE.  Northeast, southwest, and west coast influences.

Comment: Uh, did you read the script about 10 lines earlier???

Answer (score 2):

Consider it in context:

> - Hi. What's your name? Jackson Ehrenreich. We met at the cotillion, fooled around a bit in the coat check. My *dick sort of bent **hard** to
>     the left*. Yikes. Jacob, was it? Jackson.
> - Ehrenreich.
> - Right. That's a different Kelly. I think I saw her in the map room earlier. Straight down that way, *then **a hard** to the left*. Douchebag.

I don't fully understand the context, but the first italicized phrase establishes that we are talking about the penis.  Having an erection.

The second italicized clause is making a play on words.  "A hard" means "an erection".  Presumably if the individual being instructed turns left as instructed then he will experience an erection, due to sighting the "different" Kelly.

In this specific case, then, "hard" is a noun, same as "erection".

Comment: Thanks, I did get the pun, but still my question is purely grammatical in natur

Comment: @GJC -- "Hard", in this case, is a noun, same as "erection".

Answer (score 1):

If this was spoken, it is likely that one of two scenarios happened:

1. "a" was actually "uh"

> Straight down that way, then ...uh ... hard to the left

Without the vocal pause, the wording is more accurately interpreted as:

> Straight down that way, then hard to the left.

2. There were visual cues added via body language.

> Straight down that way, then a hard *[leaning]* to the left.

When interpreted as a word, the body language makes the sentence:

> Straight down that way, then a hard turn to the left.

---

Otherwise, I'd just put it up to artistic licence on the writer's part to add flavour to the character. Most people don't tend to use language accurately 100% of the time, so this could have been an intentional misstep to show human nature.

Comment: No, it's a penis joke.